# Drupal: "The directory is not writable"

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I recently upgraded my Drupal core from 6.15 to 6.26. In the update process, I was asked to make a backup of all my files, then delete the entire Drupal installation from my server, and rebuild it using the supplied files. I then copied all relevant back-up files back to the server from my local machine. The problem I'm having now is that I get a "The directory is not writable" notification whenever I do any sort of action as an admin. Initially, I was getting the error that "sites/default/files" was not writable, but I fixed that, and I changed the permissions on every file in the installation to 755. Why am I getting this error, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although permissions may be set to 755, most likely the directory ownership is set to the wrong user.

Comment: Ah, I didn't have the rights on the server to change the ownership, but I contacted the admin, and that seemed to do it. Sorry for taking so long to accept your answer!

Comment: Actually i am facing the same problem and i tried all the suggestions like permission is 755 and the owner is  Apache...but still problem is same

Answer (score 3):

Just wanted to add this possibility, which fixed this issue for me after trying many things:

If you're running SELinux (like Fedora), you may have a "security context" issue on /sites/default or /sites/default/files.  So even if you open it up using chmod 777 (not a good idea), you STILL get the permission issue.

the fix is (first cd to sites directory):

```
restorecon -rv default/
```

I ran this locally as root.

I don't pretend to be an expert on security contexts by any stretch, but Fedora documentation is [here](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Security_context?rd=SELinux/SecurityContext).

Hope that helps others avoid my headache!

Comment: WOW, you just saved my from a whole lot of time-wasting. if not for your comment, i could be searching for days and still not figure out it's an SELinux issue. THANKS A LOT!

Comment: @BLV glad it helped, the security contexts are a real PITA imo.

Answer (score 0):

After finding the permissions problem, you'll probably want to go back and chmod 644 for all files, and 755 for directories (besides the upload folder) just to be safe.

Answer (score 0):

Drupal sometimes create some directories so check if sites/default/files sub directories have the right permissions

Answer (score -1):

You can do it using two possible options:
1. change the owner of files directory and all files inside it to apache user
2. Give 777 permissions recursively to files directory